# Using ipython nbconvert with Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought, canopy

I am using Enthought/Canopy (version 1.1.0.1371) and would like to use nbconvert to convert ipython notebooks to other formats. nbconvert has now been incorporated into ipython and is not available outside of ipython. However, it is apparently not available within the Canopy distribution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is available in the current version of canopy.

You can always install canopy package the old fashioned way with setup.py, just make sure you call Canopy's python. That way, you don't have to always wait for the package manager to incorporate changes to repos.

If canopy's python is your system python, merely python setup.py install should work.  If you have multiple python paths, find Canopy's python; on my Ubuntu system it's:

```
~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
```

So I would just do:

```
~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the Canopy Package manager to update IPython to version 1.0

2) Open a Canopy User Python shell / terminal / command prompt. If you did not make Canopy your default Python, be sure to see this article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

3) ipython nbconvert ....

4) http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/profit